# Command Line Parameters

Tags: c#

I want to deploy a piece of software to pcs that will need to be able to tell the program a few pieces of information.  I do not want to use a configuration file because the exe will be located on a shared drive and they will not have access to run their own config.  Would a command line parameter be the best way to do this?  If so, how would I pass this and pick it up inside of a c# program?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you dont want to override the main method, you can use the Environment class.

```
foreach (string arg in Environment.GetCommandLineArgs())
{
    Console.WriteLine(arg);
}
```

Comment: The main difference between getting the args from main and this is that the 0-th element is the name of the executable, from Environment.

Answer (score 5):

Yes the command line is a good way of passing information to a program.  It is accessible from the `Main` function of any .Net program

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
   // Args is the command line 
}
```

From elsewhere in the program you can access it with the call `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`.  Be warned though that the command line information can be modified once the program starts.  It's simply a block of native memory that can be written to by the program

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to read a command line argument in C# is to make sure your `Main` method takes a `string[]` parameter -- that parameter is filled with the arguments passed from the command line.

```
$ cat a.cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (string arg in args)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(arg);
        }
    }
}
$ mcs a.cs
$ mono ./a.exe arg1 foo bar
arg1
foo
bar
```