# how to save data in C# Console Application?

Tags: c#, console

Hi friends  I  am  new  in C# Console Applications, I  need to  fetch data  from Command  to  Save  data  with  some  logic for Ex.

```
[ In Command Prompt I  have to  Write \]
```

i have to write this command

```
 myfile.exe  -o(parm) MyTable  Xml Filepath
```

How can i fetch these command  on my code?

Comment: Gonna take a wild stab: [Command-Line Arguments - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Command Line Parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846561/command-line-parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, then what you want to use is the string array of args used as parameter by your Main function.

A basic tutorial here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/main